# delete child and return carriage from xml

Tags: java, xml, domdocument

I have an xml file, and sometimes I have to delete some nodes.

This is my code:

```
    String xmlProduct = ""; //my xml above
    if(!xmlProduct.equals("")){
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlProduct));
        Document dom;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = (DocumentBuilderFactory) DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = (DocumentBuilder) dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         dom = db.parse(is);
         dom.normalize();


    //delete property 


    NodeList nodoProperty = dom.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Property");

    for(int i=0; i<nodoProperty.getLength(); i++){
        Node nodoBorrar = nodoProperty.item(i);
        nodoRaizXML.item(0).removeChild(nodoBorrar);

    }
 }

 //Convert to xml format

   TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   transformer.transform(new DOMSource(dom), new StreamResult(writer));
```

This is  an example of my xml:

```
<Deal>
    <SelectedDeal>+1</SelectedDeal>
</Deal>
<Property>
   <PropertyId>8215</PropertyId>
   <HPIValueChanged>1</HPIValueChanged>
 </Property>
 <FundBooking>
    <ProductCode>J128R?</ProductCode>
     <ControlNumber>            </ControlNumber>
  </FundBooking>
```

And this is what I got when executing:

```
<Deal>
   <SelectedDeal>+1</SelectedDeal>
 </Deal>


<FundBooking>  
   <ProductCode>J128R?</ProductCode>
    <ControlNumber>            </ControlNumber>
 </FundBooking>
```

the tag is deleted, but I need to delete its space in the file.

How can I do this

Comment: And how are you writing your xml back to the file huh??

Comment: I updated my code with the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the quick & dirt solution :

```
xmlProduct = xmlProduct.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");
//...
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

Comment: sorry, I'm kind a lost, I don't understand which variable is xmlProperty

Comment: @cucuru sorry I've corrected the answer. Basically you replace all carriage returns and newlines from the xml string before parsing it, and then tell the transformer to indent the output.

Comment: thanks! it doesnt work, I can't understand what is happening!

Comment: Are you getting an error or it just doesn't give the expected result? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I get the same result, the xml format but with empty lines when deleting

Comment: try to paste the output in an editor capable of showing non-printable characters (such as notepad++), and see if there is something else apart from newlines and carriage returns